# Timeout attribute in azure function isolated 6.0

Tags: azure, azure-functions, timeout, .net-6.0, dotnet-isolated

Recently I have moved my azure function from 3.0 to 6.0 Isolated, Everything works well only Timeout attribute which we are using right now **Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.TimeoutAttribute**

My code is looks like right now

```
[Timeout("-1")]
[Function("FunctionName")]
public async Task Run([BlobTrigger("blob-name/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] byte[] myBlob, string name)
{
    try
    {
        

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Timeout currently not working with Isolated 6.0 which was working previously with 3.0, Is there any different package that should be used to make it work?

*Note - I am already using premium plan for the azure function so it should at least work beyond 30 min.*

Comment: Have you tried by specifying the [functionTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout) attribute in `host.json`?

Comment: the function level timeout attribute doesn't apply for the .csx Functions (and the other languages other than the precompiled .NET)

Comment: Hi @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT that's alternate I am trying right now let me see if it that works.

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT If you can share documentation link for .csx Function doesn't apply timeout would be great help!

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1900 - check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the answer from @HariKrishnaRajoli  ([github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1900](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1900))
functionTimeout Added into host.json fixed issue.